# Testing the content of a flash message: `The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

I would like to test whether a flash message contains certain text. So I have the line:

```
assert_select flash[:info], "Your fee is valid till"
```

This however fails with the error message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '#' after ''
```

Does anyone understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only to test the message you don't need `assert_select`. Only `assert` would do.
If you wan to test printed HTML then use `assert_select`. First argument for `assert_select` is a HTML selector, like `div`.

Answer (score 18):

Try This.

```
assert_equal "Your fee is valid till", flash[:info]
```

OR

```
assert_select 'div.alert-info', flash[:info]
```